# Is git fetch notification only?

Tags: git

I am learning Git through [the book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes#Adding-Remote-Repositories) and `git help` command.

I changed the content of `origin` and commited it. Then I launched the `git fetch origin` command in my "local copy" of that repository.

```
$ git fetch origin
remote: Counting objects: 4, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.
From D:/_git.sandbox/./my_remote_project
   a03e9df..837c57d  master     -> origin/master
```

This info is not clear for me... From the book:

> As you just saw, to get data from your remote projects, you can run:
>   `$ git fetch [remote-name]`
>  The command goes out to that remote
>   project and pulls down all the data from that remote project that you
>   don’t have yet. After you do this, you should have references to all
>   the branches from that remote, which you can merge in or inspect at
>   any time.

If after `git fetch origin` I do `origin` unavailable then I get an error for `git pull`. So, in my opinion, `git pull` requeries available `origin` and uses it still instead of downloaded remote repository's changes. I.e. `git fetch` tells me that the `origin` repository was changed (if it occurred), but doesn't download these changes into my local repository. To download these changes and to implement in the local version of a repository I am to execute `git pull`. I.e. `git fetch` is a method of informing about up-dating of a repository of 'origin' when I launch 'git status'? Am I right?

Comment: Nope, you can just do `git merge origin/master` without having to do a pull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

`git fetch` downloads the remote repository's changes you don't have stored locally. It does not apply them to your local branches though.

`git pull` is a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge` of the branches you have set up to merge when pulling.

Comment: I thought about it, but if after `git fetch origin` I do `origin`  unavailable  then I get an error for `git pull`. So, `git pull` requeries available `origin` and uses it still instead of downloaded remote repository's changes.

Comment: Yes, because `git pull` is `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`. If you want to update your local branches from previously fetched changes when origin is offline, you need to `git merge origin/master master`.

Answer (score 2):

> I.e. git fetch tells me that the origin repository was changed (if it occurred), but doesn't download these changes into my local repository.

It says that it "**pulls down** all the data from that remote project that you don’t have yet", so that includes downloading the changes.

> To download these changes and to implement in the local version of a repository I am to execute `git pull`.

A `git pull` is not much more than a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`, so while it would "implement the changes" as well, doing so would render the earlier fetch obsolete.

> I.e. 'git fetch' is a method of informing about up-dating of a repository of 'origin' when I launch 'git status'? Am I right?

Not really. To prove that `git fetch` has downloaded everything already, you can simply disconnect the network and then execute this command:

```
git checkout master # optional
git merge origin/master
```

This will apply the changes without having to contact the remote again.

Comment: Thank you, @Jack for your expanded answer!

Answer (score 1):

More or less.

After a `fetch` you have downloaded the objects of your remote, in this case `origin` (the commits and references, if you want) but that doesn't change the local repository (they're not applied).
To synchronize the local `master` with `origin/master` you'd need to `merge` it in (`$ git merge origin/master`)

`pull` is just a `fetch` followed by a `merge` on the current branch. So you'd often need to just `$ git pull`.

Note that if there are several branches, only the current one will be merged after a pull (but the `fetch` works for the whole remote).

Answer (score 1):

`git fetch` only updates branches representing the remote (e.g. `origin/master`). If you want to get the changes in your local branches (e.g. `master`), you need to `git merge` them. Alternatively you can use `git pull` command which does both.

Answer (score 0):

`git fetch` *does* download the changes but does not apply them to your local branches. Try this:

```
git fetch
git log origin/master
```

The downloaded commits will be included.